# How to set up authorization policies for two controllers using Pundit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, pundit, railsapps

I'm learning Pundit using the [RailsApps Pundit Tutorial](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-devise-pundit/) and this statement from the tutorial totally confused me:

> Given that the policy object is named UserPolicy, and we will use it
>   for authorization from the Users controller, you might wrongly assume
>   that the name of the policy object will always match the name of the
>   controller. That is not the case.

1. How can I create a policy (o set of policies) that allow users with the "role_a" to use the users_controller.index action and users with the "role_b" to use the orders_controller.index action?

   1.1  Does this require two different policies (UserPolicy and OrderPolicy) or should I name the index action for every controller differently to differentiate it on the UserPolicy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it requires two different policies(***UserPolicy*** and ***OrderPolicy***)

```
#user_policy.rb
class UserPolicy
attr_reader :current_user

  def initialize(current_user)
    @current_user = current_user
  end

  def index?
    @current_user.role_a?
  end
end
```

And in your `index` method of `users_controller`

```
def index
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  authorize @user
end
```

Same for OrderPolicy

```
#order_policy.rb
class OrderPolicy
attr_reader :current_user

  def initialize(current_user)
    @current_user = current_user
  end

  def index?
    @current_user.role_b?
  end
end
```

And in your `index` method of `orders_controller`

```
def index
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  authorize @user
end
```